# My Controller function does not get any records from the database

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

Here is my controller and service layer code

```
     public class BooksController : Controller
{
   private IBookService _bookService;
    public BooksController(IBookService bookService)
    {
        _bookService = bookService;
    }
    public BooksController()
    {

    }
    // GET: Books
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        IEnumerable<Book> Books = _bookService.GetBooks().ToList();
        return View(Books);
    }
}
```

This is the code for my corresponding service layer code.

```
class BookService:ServiceBase<Book>,IBookService
{

    public BookService(IRepository<Book> repository, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork) : base(repository, unitOfWork)
    {
    }
    public IEnumerable<Book> GetBooksByName(string name)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) ? UnitOfWork.BookRepository.GetAll() : UnitOfWork.BookRepository.GetAll().Where(c => c.Name == name);
    }
    public IEnumerable<Book> GetBooks()
    {
        return UnitOfWork.BookRepository.GetAll();
    }

}
```

I am not getting any data in the view rather it says a null reference exception. I want to know how the code works because I am new to repository pattern and don't know where the problem is. Please help me in this regard.

I am using Unit of Work with the repository pattern.

Comment: Have you debugged to see where the problem exists?

Comment: Yes I have debugged the code. The Controller method IEnumerable<Books> Books = _bookService.GetBooks.ToList(); gets null values and it says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Answer (score 0):

You have two constructors in `BooksController`: one with `IBookService` param and one without.

Ho you expect your `Index()` should work if someone will use second constructor? You will receive NullReferenceException because nobody initialized `_bookService`. Well, you receving it.

Comment: I had declared a single constructor earlier but the compiler had thrown an error saying that you don't have any parameterless constructor in your controller . Tell me how to resolve that issue . I have to use the constructor with parameters.

Comment: Compiler can't force you to have parameterless constructor. C# does not deny that. Recheck that exception. And "you" can't use constructor with parameter because you do not create controllers, MVC do.

Comment: What if I need a constructor with a parameter or many parameters. I have seen this implementation in my supervisor's project.

Comment: 1) It should properly work when initiated by any of constructors. In your sample Index() will not work if controller created using parameterless constructor

Comment: 2) Controllers are created by MVC subsystem. You can't expect what constructor will be used (if many exist). May be "easiest" will be used (with less parameters), may be not :)

Comment: I have sorted out the problem to some extent. I am trying to inject a dependency in to the constructor of the controller. For that part I need a Dependency injection resolver, container. I am now trying to use Autofac to resolve dependency injection. Yet the problem is unsolved.

Comment: Injecting dependency into controller constructor is not a problem and even "traditional" ASP.NET DI subsystem can handle this. Your problem is two different constructors and one is "invalid" because controller can't work if that constructor is used.